# Reduce Bluetooth Classic Energy Usage

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a simple board with a Bluetooth module on it, and an android phone communicates to it a pulls information and data from it. However, our customers were saying that it was using too much battery life.

So, we have experimented with Bluetooth Low Energy, however, we think Bluetooth classic is the best for our current scenario.

Is there anyway, as the developer on the Android client side of things that I can do to minimize battery usage for the board with the Bluetooth module?

I.e. queuing up commands, processing them differently, etc.

Just to be clear, I am not looking to increase battery life on the phone, but rather the board with the Bluetooth module on it.

Comment: Are you using RFCOMM connection to communicate between module and android phone, if so is RFCOMM channel always open and in some interval only activity happens on the channel ?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is the way it works. We establish a socket connection between the module and the phone. And it is always open, the phone constantly listening to the socket and occasionally writing to it .

Comment: In that case, as connection is always active, it consumes a lot of power, try another approach as disconnect and reconnect only if required(if that works as per your project requirement)